# StatusBar - Alterar a cor com a rolagem em um CollapsingToolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Atualmente eu tenho uma imagem em uma tela de perfil e StatusBar está "transparente". Funcionando certinho!!

Problema:

O problema está na rolagem da tela, pois nesse caso eu já consegui fazer com que a cor da StatusBar fique na cor PrimaryDark - ao rolar (pra cima).

Código: Estou utilizando esse modelo

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout_edit_profile);
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow = false;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {       
                      Window window = activity.getWindow();
                      window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

                      window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                      window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_color));


                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(" ");
                    isShow = false;
                    Window w = activity.this.getWindow(); 
                    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATU‌​S, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                }
            }
        });
```

O que não funciona: Ao rolar a tela (pra baixo) eu tenho uma Toolbar que fica fixa. Quando termina de carregar os dados do `RecyclerView`, ai sim volta ao estado original. (com transparência)

Porém está com uma certa transparência, nessa rolagem de volta. (prints abaixo)

Preciso de alguma forma identificar quando acontece a rolagem de retorno e setar a corPrimaryDark.

Ex:

- Expanded:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Collapsed:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]